# Why JPA entities are treated like this outside a session?

Tags: jpa, entity

Hy,

I am having a "Solve failed to lazily initialize a collection of role.... exception" in jpa. I understand that outside a session, when you want to retrieve a lazy collection if there is not session bound you will get this error, fine. But what I dont understand is if I have this spring controller(the code is not 100% correct, is just to explain my case):

@Controller

```
@Autowired
EnterpriseService enterpriseService ; 

public List<Enterprise> getAll(){


    List<Enterprise> enterprises = enterpriseService.getAll();      

    for(Enterprise enterprise:enterprises){

        enterprise.getEmployees();

    }
    return enterprises;

}
```

When I call **"enterprise.getEmployees()"**, I know there is not anymore a session but why when I try to do "enterprise.getEmployees()", why enterprise is treated like a jpa entity and not just like a normal bean?, I mean; for what I understand a jpa entity is treated like this inside a session but outside like in this case it should be treated like a normal java bean so the calling to enterprise.getEmployees() should be treated like the calling of a get method of a java bean and should not throw any lazy exception....

Maybe is because spring controller treats the enterprise objects like jpa entities and not just only like java beans? this behaviour is specific to spring controllers?

Thanks

Comment: From what you are saying I would guess that you are using `AccessType.PROPERTY` in `Enterprise` - but could you add the implementation as well, it would ease the explanation of this behavior?

Comment: No, I am not using that annotation. So, is this behaviour normal? The only annotations I have are JPA annotations in Enterprise bean

Comment: If you read my answer you will know, why I wanted to see the implementation of `Enterprise`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An entity returned from an `EntityManager` is not necessarily an instance of your entity class, but a proxy class which extends your class. In many cases the same is true for the persistent properties of such entities (especially for those annotated with *(One/Many)To(One/Many)*).

For example if you are using *field based access*:

```
@Entity
public class Enterprise {
    @OneToMany
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Here the JPA provider will create a proxy class that extends `Enterprise` and remembers the previous state from the DB somehow. In addition it will change the `employees` list to its own implementation of `List` (which does not need to extend `ArrayList`).

Because the proxy class can "overwrite" your methods, it could know when you are calling `getEmployees()` and check for the session. But I don't think that this would happen here, as the method is not annotated with any JPA specific annotation.

In addition some frameworks like `Hibernate` do support *byte code enhancement* or *byte code instrumentation*. That changes the implementation of your class (in byte code) and replaces every access to `employees` with some provider specific code. I don't know if *Spring JPA* provides this, but this could lead to check for a session.

Otherwise any call to `enterprise.getEmployees()` should just return the current value of `employees` - without any check for the session and without the *LazyInitializationException*.

But calling `enterprise.getEmployees().size()` will try to initialize the list and check for the session - this could lead to the mentioned exception.

If you are using *property based access* things are a little bit different:

```
@Entity
public class Enterprise {
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Here the proxy class will *not* delegate to your implementation, but overwrite the `getEmployees()` method and return its own `List` implementation, without changing `employees`. Thus here it is possible to get a *LazyInitalizationException* for `enterprise.getEmployees()`.

*Remark*: This describes how most JPA implementations are working - but as this is implementation specific some unusual frameworks could do things differently.

Answer (score 0):

It can't do anything else. The only alternative would be to return an empty collection of employees, which would be much much worse: you would incorrectly assume that the enterprise has 0 employee, which is a valid, but completely incorrect result.

To realize how much worse it would be to do that, let's imagine a HospitalAnalysis entity, having a collection of DetectedDisease entities. And let's say you try to display the result of the analysis but forget to initialize the collection. The page would tell you that you're perfectly healthy and that you can safely go home, whereas in reality, you have a cancer, and the program has a bug. I'd much prefer the program to crash with an exception and be fixed rather than not starting my treatment.

Trying to access employees without having initialized the collection, and thus without knowing the actual collection of employees, is just a bug. This bug is signalled by throwing a runtime exception.

Comment: So, any kind of controller like Struts or Spring controllers detect what are JPA entities vs NOT JPA entities and treat them like this? Is this behaviour caused but the nature of spring or struts controller?

Comment: No. where did you get that? JPA is the one that instantiates your entity and populates it. And it populates it with a lazy collection which throws an exception when any of its method is called if the session is not there anymore, and if the collection hasn't been initialized. BTW, the posted code wouldn't throw an exception. It would if you called a method on the collection, like enterprise.getEmployees().size().

Comment: The code I posted is  pretty much the same the one I have and is throwing an exception. According to this statement :"Annotations are tags that we can insert into our program source code for some tool to process it and make sense out of it"(http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/java-annotations-explored-explained.html), you need a tool to process these annotations, so for what I understand, you need specific api(jpa api) to be aware of these annotations and I still dont get why this kind of behaviour outside a session.

Comment: I very much doubt your real code calls `getEmployees()` and completely ignores the result. Doing something with the result is what causes the exception. Why? Because the collection of employees is an instance of a special collection, not just a standard ArrayList or HashSet. This special collection doesn't contain anything until it initializes itself by executing a SQL query, the first time we use that collection. This special collection is stored in the entity by your JPA engine, when getting the enterprise from the database using the entity manager.

Comment: Your JPA engine is the tool that processes the JPA annotations.

Comment: I totally agree but from a Spring controller I think am not using any jpa api , just calling a method from a bean outside a service and outside a session and how is the JPA engine used then? I mean, I am missunderstanding something but I dont know what.

Comment: The entities used by your spring controller are returned by `enterpriseService.getAll()`. The enterpriseService uses JPA to query all the enterprises from the database and return them. So yes, you're obviously using JPA to get the enterprises. Just like when you buy a bread, the bread has been cooked in an oven, even though you never used an oven to get it. The bakery store did.

Comment: Yes, of course and I am using JPA when I call enterpriseService.getAll() from a controller but what I meant, is what jpa api I am using when I call from the controller "enterprise.getEmployees()"?

Comment: enterprise.getEmployees() returns the collection of employees inside the Enterprise entity instance. The Enterprise entity instance has been created and populated by JPA, when executing the JPA query to load enterprises from the database. JPA has thus created and populated Enterprise objects. And it has stored a special lazy collection of employees inside every Enterprise object, so that when you iterate over the employees of the enterprise, a new SQL query is executed to load the employees of the enterprise from the database automatically.

Comment: So I think, the secret is not the annotations that are only proccessed by JPA engine when I call enterpriseService.getAll() but these special collections that must have some "special code" to mean that they have to be retrieved from database, right?

Comment: Yes. Print the enterprise.getEmplyees().getClass(), and you'll see what the actual type of the collection is.

Comment: I hope my answer somehow cuts the Gordian knot of this discussion ;-)